# Vue JS CSS not updating on Browser after code changes

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack

I'm facing a strange bug on my VUS JS browser. Suddenly, some  CSS changes stopped updating on browsers.
I have a simple Footer Chid-Component nested on my Home page.  The component has been rendered on the page but the CSS properties are non in the browser.
[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Some code:  HOME PAGE

```
 <div class="home">
      <header>
        <div class="layout">
          <div class="logo"></div>
          <div class="search">
            <router-view name="NavBarSearch"></router-view>
            <router-view name="NavBar"></router-view>
    
          </div>
          <div class="nav">
            <button type="button" id="create" class="btn  rounded-pill">Create Diet</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <nav id="top">
        <div class="layout">
          <div class="space"></div>
          <div class="main">
          </div>
          <div class="tabs">
            <router-view name="Tabs"></router-view>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <nav id="left">
        <div class="container">
          <router-view name="LeftbarNav"></router-view>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <section>
        <div id="main">
        </div>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </section>
      <aside id="right">
        <div class="layout">
          <section class="main">
          </section>
          <footer class="settings">
          </footer>
        </div>
      </aside>
    
      <div class="overlay" :class={active:FullOverlay} v-on:click="mealDetails"></div>
    </div>
```

CHID-COMPONENT "Footer"

```
<template>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="left">
    
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Calendar, Stepper } from "./";
export default {
  name: "Footer",
  components: {
    Calendar,
    Stepper ,
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 110px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  .left {
    grid-area: left;
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
    background-color: transparent;
    // background-color: green;
  }
  .right {
    grid-area: right;
    grid-column: span 10;
    grid-row: span 2;
    background-color: transparent;

    // background-color: yellow;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: What are you using for the hot reloading of the browser? vue-cli "serve" command? Does that show any errors? Does the browser console show any errors?

Comment: Yes i'm using npm run serve.  no, i'm not getting any error

Comment: The footer is taking styles from two definitions: ".section .footer" and ".footer". The first is taking precedence in your screenshot, overwriting values from the second. The styles you're expecting to be applied are those in ".footer" right? Could it be a CSS specificity thing? Where is "section .footer" being defined?

Comment: Is your SCSS recompiling? Also, try removing `scoped` from the style tag, run the build and then re-add. I've had that hash not update on some occasions but the above has fixed that.

Comment: Dd you find a solution? I am having a similar problem